# How to pass a input range value to a server with ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, input, range

I need to communicate to a server the value of a input range when the submit button is clicked. I prefer not to use jQueryUi slider.

```
<input type="range" min="10" max="30" step="5" onchange="textValue.value=value" id="rangeValue">
<input type="text" maxlength="2" id="textValue" onchange="rangeValue.value=value" style="width: 25px;"> 
<input id="rangeSubmit" type="submit" class="btn"  value="Submit">
```

**jQuery code**. Is it correct to pass the value with `$("#rangeValue").val()`?

```
$("#rangeSubmit").click(function(event){
        var responseMsg = $('#response');
        responseMsg.hide()
                    .addClass("response-waiting")
                    .text('Wait...')
                    .fadeIn(200);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:80/app/test.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { range: $("#rangeValue").val() },
            success: function(data){
                //setup variables
                var responseData = data;
                var changeClass;
                if(responseData.success == "1"){
                    responseMessage(responseMsg, responseData, changeClass);
                }else{
                  if(responseData.success == "0"){
                    changeClass = "response-error";
                    responseMessage(responseMsg, responseData, changeClass);
                  }else{
                    console.log("error");
                  }
                }
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

**Php code**. This code is not working properly. Is the isset() function wrong in this case? The json array given by this code is `{"success":0,"message":"required fields are missing"}`

```
$response = array();
if(isset($_POST['rangeValue'])){
    $tmpCond = $_POST['rangeValue'];
    $query3 = "INSERT INTO condizionatore (tmpCond) VALUES ('$tmpCond')";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if($result3){
      $response['success'] = 1;
      $response['message'] = "Success!";  
      echo json_encode($response);

    } else {
      $response['success'] = 0;
      $response['message'] = 'Ops, error.';   
      echo json_encode($response); 
    }
} else {
  $response['success'] = 0;
  $response['message'] = 'required fields are missing';
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Could you please help me figuring out the problem?

Comment: You are using "range" in data: { range: $("#rangeValue").val() } in js, so your isset($_POST['rangeValue']) is wrong use isset($_POST['range'])

Comment: This `onchange="textValue.value=value"` doesn't really work...

Comment: You are right @NileshYadav, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

The first, and more important, is that you are sending data this way:

```
data: { range: $("#rangeValue").val() },
```

So, it will be sent as:

```
range=<range_val>
```

Which will generate the following `$_POST` superglobal:

```
array (
    "range" => <range_val>
)
```

But  your are testing for:

```
if(isset($_POST['rangeValue']))
```

That is, you are using the **wrong key**.

---

Second, I'm not sure this kind of thing works:

```
onchange="textValue.value=value"
```

Here is what I've got:

Added a class to both inputs and then used it to keep both autoupdated:

```js
$('.autoupdate').on('change', function(){
  $('.autoupdate').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="range" min="10" max="30" step="5" id="range-value" class="autoupdate"/>
  <input type="text" id="range-value" class="autoupdate"/>
  <input id="range-submit" type="submit"  value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it to `data: { rangeValue: $("#rangeValue").val() } `, now the key is correct but the code is not working. The ajax success function is not giving any response

Comment: If you `console.log(data)` in the response callback does it show anything?

Comment: Are the request even being sent? Check your network console.

Comment: Yes. There was a typing error. Now it works! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Correct php code is

```
$response = array();
if(isset($_POST['rangeValue'])){
    $tmpCond = $_POST['rangeValue'];
    $query3 = "INSERT INTO condizionatore (tmpCond) VALUES ('$tmpCond')";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if($result3){
      $response['success'] = 1;
      $response['message'] = "Success!";  
      echo json_encode($response);

    } else {
      $response['success'] = 0;
      $response['message'] = 'Ops, error.';   
      echo json_encode($response); 
    }
} else {
  $response['success'] = 0;
  $response['message'] = 'required fields are missing';
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```